# Computer decision mechanism

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have 5 players where they throw dice. We cannot use any external input such as onclick action or something.

How do I make the computer decide whether it is good to stop throwing? The stopping criteria is either you didn't throw 1,5 or straight or triples or higher. Everything counts as a point and if you hit something, lets say triple sixes you now can decide whether you throw again, but without these three dice. But if you fail to hit anything on the next throw, you lose every point you've got in the section. Or keep the sixes, which gives you 600 points.

```
def game(length, output = True):
    round_no = 0
    avg_pts = 0
    player_points[0,0,0,0,0]
    while output:
        round_no += 1
        for i in range 5:
            lock = true
            while lock: 
            dice_throw(number_of_throws)

def dice_throw(number_of_throws):
    throw_values = []
    for i in range(number_of_throws):
        throw_values.append(randint(1,6))
    throw_values.sort()   
    for i in range(throw_values)
```

How can I make a mechanism that decides if its good to continue throwing or not?

Comment: sorry but in your question it's not clear what's the stopping criteria. Also, what does "dice 10 000" mean?

Comment: dice 10 000 is the name of game the stopping criteria is either you didnt threw 1,5 or straight or trips or higher everything count as point and if you hit something lets say trips of sixes you now can decide whether you throw again but without these three dices but if you fail to hit anything you lose every point you ve got in the section or keep wich gives you 600 points

Comment: Your example code doesn't run; please make sure your example code is working, even if it doesn't provide the results you're looking for.